# How can I make my USB flash drive writable?

Tags: usb

I only have permission to read on my USB. It throws

```
Read only filesystem
```

What can I do to be able to write on it?

Comment: What are those *many ways* you have tried?

Comment: Please post the output of the following command, when the pendrive is plugged in (see the following comment)...

Comment: sudo lsblk -fm  #  please copy and paste the text, do not post a screenshot image

Comment: @sudodus just write it as `sudo lsblk -fm` So he can copy/paste it.

Comment: Move that little switch on the side of the pendrive to RW instead of RO ?